# matplotlib plotting incorrectly when csv files are concatted

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are two csv files mentioned in the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/deostroll/7d1e95391855245fed8a4c746be4a901

They are simple historical NAV charts of a fund. It has only two fields. `NAV` - its the price. And other field `NAV DATE` - which is date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I can run the plot program (shared below) against each file separately and observe that they appear as expected.

Here is the code I use for plotting:

```
import csv
import os
from datetime import datetime

def csv_to_jsonarray(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        rdr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator=os.linesep)
        headers = False
        res = []
        for row in rdr:
            if not headers:
                hrow = row
                headers = True
                continue
            d = dict(zip(hrow, row))
            res.append(d)
        return res

def run(file):
    arr = csv_to_jsonarray(file)
    # print(len(arr))
    xvals = []
    yvals = []
    for item in arr:
        xvals.append(datetime.strptime(item['NAV DATE'], '%Y-%m-%d'))
        yvals.append(float(item['NAV']))
        
    
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6))
    # plt.scatter(xvals, yvals)
    plt.plot(xvals, yvals)

    plt.show()
```

The `run()` is the one of interest.

But when I try to plot the csv files (manually concatenated) it prints incorrectly as shown below:

[image]

It seems to form a loop; in any capacity this is wrong! Is there an issue with my code? No issue with data exists since, I have verified it through a spreadsheet program, and, I am able to make charts correctly.

Comment: You must sort your data

Comment: Shouldn't converting the `NAV DATE` field to datetime be enough?

Comment: `xvals, yvals = zip(*sorted(zip(xvals, yvals)))` as per the duplicate

Comment: Much easier with `import pandas as pd`: `url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deostroll/7d1e95391855245fed8a4c746be4a901/raw/8db35ab49ba753e9081926aead25c001c8ead6a6/file1.csv'` or use a local file name, `df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['NAV DATE'], date_format='%Y-%m-%d').sort_values('NAV DATE', ignore_index=True)` and `ax = df.plot(x='NAV DATE')`

Comment: Given 2 files `fs = ['d:/data/data.csv', 'd:/data/data2.csv']` load the files `f = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=['NAV DATE'], date_format='%Y-%m-%d') for f in fs], ignore_index=True)` and then plot directly with pandas `ax = df.plot(x='NAV DATE', figsize=(10, 10))` does not require sorting. However, plotting with `pyplot` does: `plt.plot('NAV DATE', 'NAV', data=df.sort_values('NAV DATE'))`